# Как создать два объекта c разными средами в codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Есть приложение codeigniter использующие разные среды (environment). Среды отличаются только конфигами. Нужно в текущем объекте создать объект с другой средой. Проблема в том, что environment константа и перезагрузить конфиги стандартными методами нельзя.

Пока сделал так:

```
    unset($this->ci->session);
    $this->ci->load->library('session', $config, 'session'); //загружают класс с нужными конфигами из другой среды

    //проверяю авторизацию...

    unset($this->ci->session);
    $this->ci->load->library('session', '', 'session'); //загружают класс конфигами текущей среды
```

Есть другие варианты?

Добавлю. Это нужно для проверки авторизации в среде администратора магазина (используются другие сессии и БД). Например, если перейти в магазин нужно проверить админ ли это.

Answer (score 1):

Айайай...
Тебе нужно создать контроллер admin и в него запихнуть все методы, отвечающие за рендеринг админских страничек, после прикрутить авторизацию (не знаю как она на codeigniter делается, наверное есть куча стандартных скриптов). И уже поcле, конструктор контрроллера admin оформить следующим образом:

```
  function __construct()
  {
     if (!IsAdmin()) {
       header("Location: /");
       die();  
     }
     parent::__construct();
  }
```

Это, если сжато...

Comment: Это уже все сделано давно. Задача в другом. Вот я нахожусь в магазине (не админка) и т.к среда магазина то грузятся конфиги магазина, скрипт авторизации берет инфу из таблицы клиентов, а не таблицы администраторов, далее скрипт сессий читает другие cookies и т.д В добавок еще константы мешаются... А нужно как-то создать новый супер-объект со средой админа.

Comment: https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/environments.html

Ты вот это имеешь ввиду?

Comment: да. и тут т.к ENVIRONMENT константа, ее нельзя никаким образом временно отменить или изменить